# How to use plot inside a function?

Tags: r, function, plot, lapply

I have a list and I want to plot all data frames in it by function MyPlot, but there are several problems:

1. It just plot the last data frame (L2)
2. The names of each data frames can not be extracted by name = deparse(substitute(df))
3. If I use jpeg instead of pdf there is an error:
   "Error in switch(units, `in` = res, cm = res/2.54, mm = res/25.4, px = 1) * :
   non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Any help would be appreciated.

```
L1 = data.frame(A = c(1:4) , B = c(1:4) , C = c(1:4))
L2 = data.frame(A = c(5:8) , B = c(8:11), G = c(1:4) )
L=list(L1,L2)
names(L) = c('L1' , 'L2')

MyPlot <- function(df){
  name = deparse(substitute(df))
  jpeg(paste(name) , ".jpg")
  #pdf(paste0(name,".pdf"), onefile = TRUE, paper = "A4")
  P = ggplot(df, aes(A , B)) + geom_point()
  #print(P)
  dev.off()

}
Plot_jpeg = L %>% lapply(MyPlot)
```

Comment: With ggplot, use `ggsave` rather than `jpeg()` or `pdf()`, and that will solve the units error.

Comment: But you can't use `depase/substitue` with `lapply`. The `lapply` changes the name of variables when it runs your function and your function doens't have access to the list names. Functions like `purrr::imap` try to make it easier to get to the names, but using substitute will not get original variables names with any sort of apply-like function.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for the prompt response. ggsave just save the last plot by default. I don't know how should I use grid.arrange inside the function.

Comment: You want all the plots in one pdf/jpeg? Because right now it looks like your function is trying to make one pdf/jpeg per data frame

Answer (score 2):

This might not be what you want, but:

```
L1 = data.frame(A = c(1:4) , B = c(1:4) , C = c(1:4))
L2 = data.frame(A = c(5:8) , B = c(8:11), G = c(1:4) )
L=list(L1,L2)
names(L) = c('L1' , 'L2')

MyPlot <- function(df, name){
  P = ggplot(df, aes(A , B)) + geom_point()
  ggsave(P, glue::glue("{name}.jpeg")
  return(P)

}
Plots_list = purrr::map2(L, names(L), 
function(.x, .y) MyPlot(.x, .y))
```

As MrFlick suggests,
a more idiomatic purrr option could be `purrr::imap(L, ~MyPlot(.x, .y))` since `imap(x, ...)` is short hand for `map2(x, names(x), ...)`. I am using `map2` because I would rather be explicit, less things to remember.

Comment: Perhaps a more idiomatic `purrr` option would be `Plots_list <- purrr::imap(L, ~MyPlot(.x, .y))`